# Notification order after the release of a lock in java (android)

Tags: java, android, synchronization

I'm writing a simple **file cache**. In this context, I would like to implement **three methods** to modify a file : `create`, `read` and `delete`.

When a file is subject to deletion, I intend to first check whether it's being read and delete it afterwards. I first want to give a **priority to the call to `read` over `delete`**. But I also want the **`read` to be able to be executed by multiple threads**. (non-exclusive lock)

My first idea was to have a synchronized counter to monitor the number of reads going on with each file in my cache. When delete is called, it checks whether the counter > 0, if yes, it loops and waits until it's set to zero and continues. I don't like this loop and would like to use a safer mechanism.

I would be glad to hear any suggestion.

Thank you

Comment: Code improvement suggestions are usually made when code is already written - from your question it's unclear if you have already tried. It's better to have a working solution that you don't like than no solution at all.
Feel free to give it a go, update your answer with your code and I bet that you'll get some answers. :)

Comment: I ended up using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html
I noticed a new library made by Facebook called Fresco: https://github.com/facebook/fresco
Right now it seems a bit buggy, but their memory management is quite effective and until Android 5.0 is popular enough, it will be very nice to use.